# jQuery - make a DIV visible on the browser

Tags: jquery

I have designed a long form around two pages. After the user submits the form, I need to force him/her to see the top of the form if the form contains any errors.

I have an error holder on top of the form.

My question is how to make the browser scrolls to the error holder so that the user can easily see it?

Thank you

/////////////////////////////////////////// follow Peter's comments

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // This is a functions that scrolls to the element with id id
    function goToByScroll(id)
    {
        // Scroll
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(id).offset().top}, 'slow');
    };

    $(document).ready( function() {
      debugger;
      $('#clearhere').click(function() {
        goToByScroll('topbar2');
      });
    });

    </script>    

</head>
<body>
    <div id="topbar2">Hello world</div>

    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>



    <button type="button" id="clearhere" name="clearhere">Click Me!</button>    
</body>
</html>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: `goToByScroll('#topbar2');` . Note the hash sign. You have to call the function using a literal jQuery selector. Here is your code working: http://jsfiddle.net/F4TQ5/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To scroll to the top an element simply make use of the jQuery [**.animate()**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [**.offset()**](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) functions. For example to scroll to the top of an element with a particular selector (such as an id) passed in as an argument, [use this](http://djpate.com/2009/10/07/animated-scroll-to-anchorid-function-with-jquery/):

```
  // This is a function that scrolls to the element that matches selector
function goToByScroll(selector){
      // Scroll
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top},
        'slow');
};
```

For example, if you have only one form on the page, you can use: `goToByScroll("form");`. If you want to scroll to an element with a particular id use `goToByScroll("#myId");` ... etc.

If you want to adjust the scroll time to an exact number of milliseconds, just replace `'slow'` with the number of millisecond, for example `1000` (no quotes) for a scroll of 1 second.

Just trigger the above function when you want to scroll to the top of your form.

[**Here's a live jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/TrXmw/) ([*as a 5 line jQuery plugin*](http://jsfiddle.net/G5X8V/))

Comment: Hello Peter,

I have tried this method. However, it doesn't work for me.

The firebug reports:

Break on ErrorCopy
$(id).offset() is null

Thank you

Comment: @q0987 - What is id? How did you call the function? Sounds like a problem with that. Take a look at how I call the function in the jsFiddle examples.

Comment: Hello Peter,

I have posted my script following my original question. I have used firebug to debug and it reports the error as above.

Thank you

Comment: @q0987 `goToByScroll('#topbar2');` . Note the hash sign. You have to call the function using a literal jQuery selector. I got your code to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/F4TQ5/

Comment: Hello Peter,

Thank you so much for your helps.

Just curious, why you choose to use $('html, body').animate rather than just $('html').animate.

I found that $('body').animate doesn't work for me.

Thank you

Comment: @q0987 - Firefox and IE use `body` in quirks mode. So selecting both `html` and `body` covers all the bases.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the jQuery [ScrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) to smoothly scroll back up to the error holder:

```
// in your validation, on error
$(window).scrollTo($('#errorHolderId'), 500);
```

**Sans plugin**

If you don't want to use a plugin, you can do it with a combination of [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset) or [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position) and [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/):

```
var errorHolderTop = $('#errorHolderId').offset().top;
$(window).scrollTop(errorHolderTop);
```

The reason I mentioned both offset and position is because they behave slightly differently.  Offset returns coordinates relative to the document whereas position is relative to your element's offset parent.

You could also animate the scrollTop property if you wanted to create the smooth scroll effect:

```
var errorHolderTop = $('#errorHolderId').offset().top;
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: errorHolderTop});
```

[In action here](http://jsfiddle.net/asHeH/).

Comment: Hello Pat,

Is there way that I don't have to use a extra plugin?

Thank you

Comment: @q0987 sure, see my edits for a few different ways of doing it.

Comment: Hello Pat,

Interesting here. Both you and Peter use $('html, body') rather than just $('html'). any reason?

Thank you

Comment: @q0987 cross-browser compatibility my good man.  Some browsers want to scroll the `html` element, others want the `body`.